# How to Create Animation Path Data

Tags: wpf, animation, svg

hi how i can create animation path data for use in wpf? for example this data draw a H character

```
M40.493382,19.001303 C36.637875,19.06448 33.938568,21.421986 33.948524,25.271919 L34.068279,71.56765 34.066906,71.598007 34.068745,71.747833 34.18895,118.21758 C34.202225,123.35083 39.026951,129.19344 44.965271,131.2674 50.903587,133.34137 55.706783,130.86133 55.693504,125.72808 L55.589508,85.524513 93.866371,85.524513 93.950943,118.21758 C93.964218,123.35083 98.788948,129.19344 104.72726,131.2674 110.66558,133.34137 115.46878,130.86133 115.4555,125.72808 L115.33575,79.432381 115.33712,79.401993 115.33528,79.252007 115.21507,32.782413 C115.2018,27.64917 110.37708,21.806566 104.43876,19.732603 98.500435,17.658638 93.697243,20.138674 93.710518,25.271919 L93.814514,65.475487 55.537647,65.475487 55.453079,32.782413 C55.439804,27.64917 50.615082,21.806566 44.676762,19.732603 43.192181,19.214111 41.778549,18.980244 40.493382,19.001303 z M9.999999,0 L140,0 C145.52284,0 150,4.4771523 150,9.999999 L150,140 C150,145.52284 145.52284,150 140,150 L9.999999,150 C4.4771523,150 0,145.52284 0,140 L0,9.999999 C0,4.4771523 4.4771523,0 9.999999,0 z
```

is there any application to write some character and export it in animation path data?

Comment: What have you tried? You may use Geometry.Parse and a MatrixAnimationUsingPath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Metro Studio from Syncfusion. It's free and gives output in multiple formats.Following is the code for H. This is just an example. You can customize as per your requirement.

```
<Viewbox x:Shared="false" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
  <Grid>
    <Grid Name="backgroundGrid" Width="256" Height="256" Visibility="Collapsed" />
    <Path Stretch="Uniform" Fill="#FF007ACC" Width="156" Height="156" Margin="0,0,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
      <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry FillRule="Nonzero" Figures="M7.68750047683716,19.7579193115234L16.78125,19.7579193115234 16.78125,47.9766693115234 52.5,47.9766693115234 52.5,19.7579193115234 61.59375,19.7579193115234 61.59375,88.4766693115234 52.5,88.4766693115234 52.5,56.0860443115234 16.78125,56.0860443115234 16.78125,88.4766693115234 7.68750047683716,88.4766693115234 7.68750047683716,19.7579193115234z" />
      </Path.Data>
      <Path.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
          <TransformGroup.Children>
            <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1" ScaleY="1" />
          </TransformGroup.Children>
        </TransformGroup>
      </Path.RenderTransform>
    </Path>
  </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```